# Chances for $3$ 6-sided die and $2$ 8-sided die to have a sum of $12$

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

If $5$ dice are rolled, $3$ 6-sided die and $2$ 8-sided die, how do I come up with the chances that the sum will be $12$?

I've figured that there are $13824$ total combinations, but can't figure out the number of combinations that equal $12$.

What formula or method should I use?

Comment: You could use generating functions...find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $ (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)^2$.  that is easily done in Wolfram Alpha, say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather straightforward to do using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), since only one of the constraints can be violated at a time.

There are $\binom{12-1}{5-1}=330$ ways to distribute $12$ balls to $5$ non-empty bins, of which $3\cdot\binom{12-6-1}{5-1}=15$ have more than $6$ balls in one of the $3$ bins with capacity $6$. All other constraint violations and combinations thereof are impossible, so the result is $330-15=315$, in agreement with the result of the generating function solution given by lulu in a comment.

Comment: +1 Yes, that is neat. It did not occur to me to think of it that way!